# Monitorar espaço em datafile sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Geralmente eu não deixo os banco de dados crescerem de forma automática até o limite do disco. Portanto, gostaria de saber se os colegas tem alguma Procedure para que eu possa monitorar e ser alertado de quando o espaço em um Datafile está acabando. Seja ele de log ou de dados.

Exemplo:

Supondo que eu tenha um banco cliente e limitei seu espaço para que ele cresça até 10 MB e log até 3 MB.

Quando atingir 97% do espaço usado, gostaria de ser avisado seja do log ou do datafile.

Answer (score 3):

A partir da versão SQL Server 2008 você pode fazer uma consulta a visão de catálogo [`sys.database_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174397(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() as NomeBD,
    name as NomeArquivo,
    size/128 as TamanhoMB,
    max_size/128 as MaxTamanhoMB,
    cast(100 * cast(size as float) / max_size as varchar(max)) + '%' as OcupacaoArquivo
FROM sys.database_files;
```

Resultado:

```
Nome BD         NomeArquivo         TamanhoMB   MaxTamanhoMB    OcupacaoArquivo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MeuBancoDados   MeuBancoDados             126            400                31%
MeuBancoDados   MeuBancoDados_log         139            600                23%
```

Você então pode usar essa consulta numa *procedure* que envia e-mail e agendar um *job* no SQL Server. Claro, você pode também usar ela numa *View* e usar um pequeno aplicativo para monitorar. Ou rodar na mão mesmo, quando quiser.
<sub>(Não vou detalhar essa parte porque não faz parte do âmbito da pergunta.)</sub>

#### Observação 1:

Precisamos converter o campo "size" para `float` para obter os decimais. Se não ocorrer a conversão, ocorre a divisão inteira (`int/int`), truncando as decimais. Um 99,999% de ocupação, seria informado como "só" 99%.

Por exemplo, para um limite de 10GB, o arquivo pode estar a ~100KB do limite, enquanto seria informado que estaria a 100MB.

#### Observação 2:

Note que as colunas `size` e `max_size` não informam o tamanho em alguma unidade múltipla de Bytes. Eles informam em unidades de [página](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx). A página tem 8KB por definição da arquitetura do SQL Server, desde a versão 7.0.

Multiplicando o número de páginas pelo espaço ocupado, temos o espaço ocupado em KB.
Para calcular esses valores em MB:

```
TamanhoMB = size * 8 / 1024
          = size / 128
```

---

**NOTA:** Numa primeira versão dessa resposta, disse que era preferível usar `decimal` sobre `float` no cálculo. Voltei atrás porque a diferença é desprezível para essa conta, na 4ª casa decimal em casos mais extremos.
Deixei como `float` para deixar a query mais limpa (e ocupar menos espaço durante a execução, míseros 1 Bytes usando valores padrões).